# SQL Cumulative Total for Tax year July to June

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, cumulative-sum

Trying to get a cumulative total on the far right column that would reset to start over on July of each year. Tax year is July to June. This code resets calendar year.:

```
Select T.MonthlyTotal
      ,T.SalesMonth
      ,T.[Year]
      ,SUM(T.MonthlyTotal) OVER (ORDER BY T.[Year]) AS CumulativeTotal 
        From (SELECT 
        SUM (SubTotal) AS MonthlyTotal
        ,MONTH(CreateDate) AS SalesMonth
        ,Year(CreateDate) AS [Year]
        FROM OrderFormHeader
        Group by Month(CreateDate),Year(CreateDate)) AS T

  Order by T.[Year],T.SalesMonth
```

Sample data:

```
MonthlyTotal    SalesMonth  Year    CumulativeTotal
34370.56               7    2009    135682.15
61915.29               8    2009    135682.15
15027.21               9    2009    135682.15
9537.80               10    2009    135682.15
6748.38               11    2009    135682.15
8082.91               12    2009    135682.15
9047.77                1    2010    446574.06
11152.21               2    2010    446574.06
11672.16               3    2010    446574.06
13451.61               4    2010    446574.06
10777.37               5    2010    446574.06
20135.99               6    2010    446574.06
55169.70               7    2010    446574.06
93018.89               8    2010    446574.06
50195.15               9    2010    446574.06
11842.17               10   2010    446574.06
```

Comment: add salesmonth to your SUM() OVER()? `SUM(T.MonthlyTotal) OVER (ORDER BY T.[Year], T.SalesMonth)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the partitioning scheme of your data:

```
select SUM(SubTotal) AS MonthlyTotal, MONTH(CreateDate) AS SalesMonth,
       Year(CreateDate) AS [Year],
       SUM(SUM(SubTotal)) OVER (PARTITION BY MIN(Year(DATEADD(month, 6, CreateDate)))
                                ORDER BY MIN(MONTH(DATEADD(month, 6, CreateDate)))
                               ) as FY_YTD
from OrderFormHeader
Group by Month(CreateDate), Year(CreateDate)
Order by [Year], SalesMonth;
```

You can use a trick of adding six months to the date, to get the "tax" month.  Then, you can use this information to extract the year and month for the cumulative sum.

Note that you don't need subqueries.  You can mix aggregation functions with window functions.